# Showing the set of real values for which the pre-image has measure greater than zero is measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The question is stated as follows:

Show that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then the set $E = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ m(f^{-1}(x)) > 0 \}$ has measure zero.

This problem seems simple enough at first glance, and I feel like I had a solution. We begin by showing that $E$ is measurable using a definition from Royden. That is, since $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, and we have
\begin{align}
m^*(\mathbb{R}) = m^*(\mathbb{R} \cup E) + m^*(\mathbb{R} \cup E^C) 
\end{align}

it follows that $E$ is a measurable set. Traditionally, if the inverse of $f$ is defined, then f is bijective and for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$, there should be one $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = y$. But then for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $m(f^{-1}(y)) = m(\{x\}) = 0$. From this, it should follow not only that $E$ is empty, but that $m(E) = 0$.

Here is where I'm not sure. If we just consider $f^{-1}$ to return the pre-image of a point $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and say that $f$ is a constant function defined $f(x) = c$, then $m(f^{-1}(c)) = m(\mathbb{R}) = \infty > 0$. In this case, however, $E = \{c\}$, which has measure zero. With this new interpretation of $f^{-1}$, I'm not exactly sure how to proceed. If the measure of $E$ was not zero, there would necessarily be an interval $(y_1,y_2) \subset E$ for which each point in the interval $y \in (y_1,y_2)$, we have $f^{-1}(y) = (x_1,x_2)$. I'm not sure what implications this might have, if any. Should I work at obtaining a contradiction here, or should I attempt to prove that $m(E) = 0$ directly?

Edit: As was pointed out in the comments, my argument for the measurability of $E$ is insufficient. Further, my conclusion that an interval lived in $E$ is equally false (thanks Cantor)

Comment: Your argument that $E$ is measurable is insufficient. To apply the definition of measurability directly, you need to show that for *any* test set $T\subset\mathbb{R}$, the outer measure of $T$ is that of $T\cap E$ plus that of $T\cap E^c$. However, it may be more efficient to base the argument on consequences of the measurability of $f$.

Comment: Also: you are right in the last paragraph that $f^{-1}(x)$ in this context means "return the whole preimage of $x$" and does not imply that an inverse function is defined.

Comment: Lastly: the assumption of $E$ being measure not zero does *not* imply that it contains an interval in which all the preimages of points are intervals. In fact, a set of positive measure needn't contain any intervals. (Google "positive measure nowhere dense".)

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith, you are correct, I had missed that detail. Would you suggest I remove it? As it's not sufficient, it doesn't really add to the problem, and I am now left without a statement that $E$ is measurable. Thanks for catching this

Edit: Actually, thank you for catching all of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ doesn't even have to be measurable for this to be true.  (Of course, if $f$ isn't measurable, then there may exist $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(x)$ is not a measurable set, but that's OK — any such $x$ won't be in $E$ since it's not true that $m\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)\gt 0.)$

If $f$ isn't required to be measurable, we're interpreting $E$ as $\lbrace x\;\vert\;f^{-1}(x)\text{ is measurable and }m(f^{-1}(x))>0\rbrace$ or, equivalently, $\lbrace x\;\vert\;f^{-1}(x)\text{ has positive measure}\rbrace.$

As @DavidC.Ullrich pointed out, $E$ will actually turn out to be countable.

For positive integers $s$ and $t,$ let $E_{s,t} = \lbrace x\;\vert\; m\left([t,t+1) \cap f^{-1}(x) \right) \gt \frac{1}{s} \rbrace . $

Claim: Each $E_{s,t}$ is finite.  In fact, the cardinality of $E_{s,t}$ is less than $s.$

Proof of claim: Suppose $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are $n$ distinct elements of $E_{s,t};$ we'll show that $n \lt s.$  The sets $f^{-1}(x_1), \dots, f^{-1}(x_n)$ are pairwise disjoint, so
$$1 = m\left([t,t+1)\right) \ge \sum_{k=1}^{n}m\left([t,t+1)\cap f^{-1}(x_n)\right) \gt \frac{n}{s},$$  where the last inequality is because each of the $n$ summands is greater than $\frac{1}{s}.$  It follows that $n \lt s.$

Now define $E_t = \lbrace x\;\vert\; m\left([t,t+1) \cap f^{-1}(x) \right) \gt 0 \rbrace .$  A real number $a$ is greater than $0$ iff there is a positive integer $s$ such that $a$ is greater than$\frac{1}{s};$ so $E_t = \cup \lbrace E_{s,t}\;\vert\; s\text{ is a positive integer}\rbrace.$  This is a countable union of finite sets, so each $E_t$ is countable.

Next we observe that if a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ has positive measure, then, for some integer $t,$ the set $A \cap [t,t+1)$ has positive measure.  After all, each of the sets $A \cap [t,t+1)$ is the intersection of two measurable sets, so is measurable; but if they all had measure $0,$ then $A$ would be the countable union of measure $0$ sets, so $A$ would have measure $0$ itself.

It follows that $E \subseteq \cup \lbrace E_t\;\vert\;t\text{ is an integer}\rbrace.$  The union here is a countable union of countable sets, so it must be countable.  Its subset $E$ must therefore be countable also. Any countable set has measure $0,$ so we're done.

Finally, a note on the axiom of choice: this argument doesn't use the axiom of choice although it may at first appear to.  (The general theorem that a countable union of finite sets is countable *does* require the axiom of choice, as does the theorem that a countable union of countable sets is countable.  But in the particular cases used here, the axiom of choice is not needed.)

The reason that choice isn't required here is that the reals are linearly ordered (by the usual ordering), and this linear ordering provides a specific, definable well-ordering of each of our finite sets $E_{s,t}.$  This in turn gives us a way to define a specific counting of each of the sets $E_t,$ and that's all that's needed to conclude that their union is countable.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to write this out, as my text has a pretty limited section on $\sigma$-finite sets. One question I have - we start with the assumption that $E$ has $n$ distinct elements, which we use to build the rest of the proof. How do we know that this is true? You did mention that each $f^{-1}(x_i)$ would be disjoint and have measure greater than $\frac{1}{s}$, so it makes sense that at most, you would have to have less than $s$ distinct elements. Is this the justification for it?

Comment: Yes, that's right, except that it's actually $[t,t+1) \cap f^{-1}(x)$ that we need to know has cardinality greater than $1/s.$  What I showed was that if $n$ is any natural number such that there exist $n$ distinct members of $E_s,t.$ then $n$ must be less than $s;$ it follows from this implication that $E_s,t$ has cardinality less than $s.$

Comment: It might be clearer to phrase the proof of the Claim as a proof by contradiction: Assume the cardinality of $E_s,t \ge s.$  Then there exist $s$ distinct elements $x_1, \dots, x_s$ of $E_s,t,$ and we can proceed as before, with $n$ replaced by $s,$ to see that $$1 = m\left([t,t+1)\right) \ge \sum_{k=1}^{s}m\left([t,t+1)\cap f^{-1}(x_s)\right) \gt \frac{s}{s} = 1,$$ which is a contradiction, proving the Claim.

Comment: I assume it's clear, but all instances of $E_s,t$ in my two comments above should be $E_{s,t}$ -- too much time has passed to edit the comments and fix the MathJax.

Comment: That's perfectly clear. It felt more concrete once I started to formally try to make the argument. In my original comment, I had meant to ask about $E_{s,t}$ rather than $E$, and the rest of what you had said followed smoothly. I had considered the contradiction, but once you show that $n < s$, it followed that that was true for every value of $n$. In particular, since the set of $\{ f^{-1}(x_i) \}$ had to be pairwise disjoint, it had to be that we could not have more than $s$ distinct $x_i$s. Thank you again for your explanation, it was incredibly helpful

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Since Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite it follows that $E$ is actually *countable*.